# Как добавить новое состояние в state в vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

есть необходимость после отрисовки страницы добавить несколько состояний в глобальное хранилище (их количество рандомно). Названия должны быть однотипны (по типу item_, item__ или еще лучше (даже не знаю что придумать)). Как я могу это реализвать? Если это вообще разрешено. Vuex начал изучать недавно.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вы можете в state хранить объект, поля которого и будут вашими состояниями

```
state: {
    currentStates: {}, // Ваши состояния тут
},
mutations: {
    // Мутация для обновления ваших состояний
    upload (state, newStates) {
        state.currentStates = newStates
    },
},
actions: {
    // Экшн для обновления ваших состояний
    upload ({ commit }, newStates) {
        commit('upload ', newStates)
    },
}
```

Вытаскивать - изменять как вам нужно - заливать обратно